# Sudden velocity changes and their impact on a Turtlebot

Tags: ros, dynamixel, ros-kinetic, opencr, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a Turtlebot3. Their provided "teleop" code example the code makes sure that the velocity requested via cmd_vel messages don't change too quickly too radically.  However many of the other examples seem to just send cmd_vel's without worrying too much about ramping. Some say that the motors (dynamixels) or the motor controller board (opencr) will make sure that the ramping happens and that cmd_vels above the maximum speeds are ignore. I am having a hard time getting clear on this.

So my question is:  If I send a series of cmd_vel with for example x = 0.15 and immediately follow it with a cmd_vel with x = 0, with that harm the robot in any way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300208/sudden-velocity-changes-and-their-impact-on-a-turtlebot/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know about TB3, but on TB2 (kobuki base), the `yocs_velocity_smoother` nodelet takes care of properly filtering incoming `Twist`s.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0